# Unable to recognize speech from microphone using Azure Speech to Text service in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-speech

I wrote code in react js to identify text from speech from the microphone, its unable to identify or recognized the speech, and here there is no error and I tried couple of option it is not working.

```
const startSpeechRecognition = async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

    speechRecognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();
    speechRecognizer.recognized = (s, e) => {
      if (e.result.reason === ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
        const recognizedText = e.result.text;
        console.log('Ask: ' + recognizedText);
      }
    };
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          startSpeechRecognition();
        }}
      >
        Start
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

Here I tried listing the microphone only once but does not able recognize the speech

```
const reco = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig);
    const conn = Connection.fromRecognizer(reco);
    conn.setMessageProperty('speech.context', 'phraseDetection', {
      INTERACTIVE: {
        segmentation: {
          mode: 'custom',
          segmentationSilenceTimeoutMs: 5000,
        },
      },
      mode: 'Interactive',
    });

    reco.recognizeOnceAsync(
      (result) => {
        console.log('Recognition done!!!');
        // do something with the recognition
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Recognition failed. Error:' + error);
      },
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          startSpeechRecognition();
        }}
      >
        Start
      </button>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Can You specify your issue briefly and also update the original post with the latest code which you tried recently.

Comment: Hi Balaji,

I am unable to recognize the speech from microphone using react js and Azure speech service and there is no error, It was working earlier and I check azure portal, I am using free trial and it has quota to use this service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with below code which recognizes the Speech and shows the Text accordingly. I created a **Azure Speech Service** in Azure Portal and connected in my code.

**Below is the code I tried with:**

```js
function SpeechRecognitionComponent() {
  const [recognizedText, setRecognizedText] = useState('');
  const [isListening, setIsListening] = useState(false);

  const startSpeechRecognition = async () => {
    const subscriptionKey = '*****';
    const serviceRegion = '*****';

    const speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey, serviceRegion);
    const audioConfig = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();

    const recognizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

    recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync((result) => {
      if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
        const recognized = result.text;
        setRecognizedText(recognized);
      } else {
        console.error('Recognition failed. Error:', result.errorDetails);
      }
      setIsListening(false);
    });

    setIsListening(true);
  };

  const stopSpeechRecognition = () => {
    setIsListening(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Speech Recognition Example</h1>
      <button onClick={isListening ? stopSpeechRecognition : startSpeechRecognition}>
        {isListening ? 'Stop' : 'Start'} Listening
      </button>
      {isListening && <p>Listening...</p>}
      <div>
        <strong>Recognized Text: </strong>
        {recognizedText}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- I used `Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK` in the code.
- An `SpeechRecognizer` instance is created which is used to initiate speech recognition.
- Used `recognizeOnceAsync()` method to start a single recognition session. In this it listens to speech and stops after recognizes the speech. All the speech is stored into `recognizedText`.
- For further please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/sample-repository-for-the-microsoft-cognitive-services-speech-sdk/).

**Output:**
[image]